# Expand svg tab as text expands without stretching the sides

Tags: css, svg, tabs

I have tabs with svg background that stretches to the width of the text. Is there a way to edit my svg or css to fix the curvatures on the sides without splitting up the svg to separate elements or using pseudo after/before css? This way while the whole svg stretches the middle part, the sides would remain intact stretching only the middle rectangle element.

This would fix the "Other important specification" tab's stretched sides.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav-tabs li').click(function() {
        $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.product-info .row,
.recipe-info .row {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.product-info .nav-tabs,
.recipe-info .nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #def0f8;
}
.product-info .nav-tabs > li,
.recipe-info .nav-tabs > li {
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}
.product-info .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.recipe-info .nav-tabs > li > a:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.product-info .nav-tabs > li > a,
.recipe-info .nav-tabs > li > a {
  border: none;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.product-info .nav-tabs > li > a .tabbed,
.recipe-info .nav-tabs > li > a .tabbed {
  margin: 0;
  height: 35px;
  width: auto;
}
.product-info .nav-tabs > li > a .tabbed span,
.recipe-info .nav-tabs > li > a .tabbed span {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #616161;
  line-height: 35px;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline;
  white-space: nowrap;
  min-width: 95px;
}
.product-info .nav-tabs > li.active > a,
.recipe-info .nav-tabs > li.active > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 10;
}
.product-info .nav-tabs > li.active > a .tabbed,
.recipe-info .nav-tabs > li.active > a .tabbed {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns:dc='http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/' xmlns:cc='http://creativecommons.org/ns%23' xmlns:rdf='http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns%23' xmlns:svg='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' viewBox='0 0 134.5 35' preserveAspectRatio='none' data-name='Layer 1' id='Layer_1'%3E%3Cmetadata id='metadata15'%3E%3Crdf:RDF%3E%3Ccc:Work rdf:about=''%3E%3Cdc:format%3Eimage/svg+xml%3C/dc:format%3E%3Cdc:type rdf:resource='http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage' /%3E%3Cdc:title%3Etab%3C/dc:title%3E%3C/cc:Work%3E%3C/rdf:RDF%3E%3C/metadata%3E%3Cdefs id='defs3'%3E%3Cstyle id='style5'%3E.cls-1%7Bfill:%2325437f;%7D%3C/style%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Ctitle id='title7'%3Etab%3C/title%3E%3Cpath style='fill:%2325437f;fill-opacity:1' id='path9' transform='translate%280 0%29' d='M0,35H30V0C6.39,0,11.8,35,0,35Z' class='cls-1' /%3E%3Cpath style='fill:%2325437f;fill-opacity:1' id='path11' transform='translate%280 0%29' d='M134.5,35h-30V0C128.11,0,122.7,35,134.5,35Z' class='cls-1' /%3E%3Crect y='-5.5511151e-17' x='29.5' height='35' width='56.5%25' id='rect4143' style='opacity:1;fill:%2325437f;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 35px;
  background-position: center;
}
.product-info .nav-tabs > li.active > a .tabbed span,
.recipe-info .nav-tabs > li.active > a .tabbed span {
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 35px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel='stylesheet'>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-info tabbable">
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">
                    <div class="tabbed">
                        <span class="">Details</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">
                    <div class="tabbed">
                        <span class="">Other important specification</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="tab-content">
            lorem ipsum
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Probably nested svg's could solve this, here's a notion of how I imagine achieving the rightly expanding svg:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="100%" height="35">
         <defs>
          <style>
          </style>
         </defs>
         <title>expandable tab</title>
         <!--
         Whole tab as one path, if possible try to adjust the beizer curves so they
         would keep the sides unstreched when image is streched on x axis.
         -->
         <!--
         <path fill="#25437f" d="
                  m30 0
                  c-23.5,0 -18,35 -30,35
                  h30 40 30
                  c-12,0 -6.5,-35 -30,-35
                  z"
        />
         -->
        
         <!--
        The sides should have fixed widths of 30, the middle uses up the available space in between.
         -->
         <g fill="#25437f">
           <svg x="0" width="30" class="container-left">
             <path d="m0 35h30v-35c-23.61 0-18.2 35-30 35z" class="path-left" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
           </svg>
<svg x="29" width="90%" style="overflow: hide;">
              <!--
              Should have width of 100% shrunken with 30 on the x axis.
              Maybe apply a mask?
              -->
               <rect height="35" width="100%" y="-5.5511e-17"/>
           </svg>
<svg x="100%" width="30" class="container-right" transform='translate(-30 0)'>
             <!--
             Its positioning should be counted from the right to left x="0" starting from right if direction could be set.
             Hacking with x="100%" and transform="translate(-30 0)" should be doing the same, but they are not.
             -->
               <path d="m0 35h-30v-35c23.61 0 18.2 35 30 35z" class="path-right" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
           </svg>
</g>
</svg>
```

I'm looking for an implementation that uses pure html/svg/css techniques to adjust the tab size (no javascript adjustments). My goal with this is to replace an html hackery with left, middle and right blocks with one html element thus reducing the chance to mess the tab up, and renders the same way across browsers (from IE11>).

Sticking to my code structure with background-image, related css rules of course is not necessary, there could be even pure svg solutions with `<text/>` tags just to achieve the expanding tab as the text grows with non-stretching side paths.

Related interesting links:

- https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/mimic-relative-positioning-in-svg/
- https://codepen.io/gionkunz/pen/KDvLj
- https://jsfiddle.net/boldewyn/taorj2q6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I tried changing this for you, and used pure CSS with 3 classes (left, middle, and right) - with different SVG base64 data for each. Still feels a bit hacky, but let me know if this is closer to what you are looking for.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   
 $('.nav-tabs li').click(function() {
   $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('active'); 
   $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
ul {
display:block;
width: 100%;
}
li {
list-style:none;
}
.tabbed {
display:inline-block;
}
.nav-tabs {
display: inline-flex;
width: 100%;
}
.tab-content {
margin-top:50px;
margin-left:70px;
}

.tabText {
position:relative;
color:white;
display:inline-block;
z-index:10;
padding:10px;
height:35px;
vertical-align:top;
}

.left {
display:inline-block;
margin:0;
padding:0;
height: 35px;
width: 35px;
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' id='Layer_1' xmlns:cc='http://creativecommons.org/ns' xmlns:dc='http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/' xmlns:rdf='http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns' xmlns:svg='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 30 35' enable-background='new 0 0 30 35' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Cpath id='left' fill='%2325437F' d='M0,35h30V0C6.4,0,11.8,35,0,35z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
}
.middle {
display:inline-block;
margin:0;
padding:0;
background-color: #25437F;
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' id='Layer_1' xmlns:cc='http://creativecommons.org/ns' xmlns:dc='http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/' xmlns:rdf='http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns' xmlns:svg='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 56.5 35' enable-background='new 0 0 56.5 35' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Crect id='middle' fill='%2325437F' width='56.5' height='35'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
width:auto;
height:35px;
margin-left:-6px;
}
.right {
display:inline-block;
margin:0;
padding:0;
height: 35px;
width: 35px;
margin-left:-6px;
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' id='Layer_1' xmlns:cc='http://creativecommons.org/ns' xmlns:dc='http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/' xmlns:rdf='http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns' xmlns:svg='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 30 35' enable-background='new 0 0 30 35' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Cpath id='right' fill='%2325437F' d='M30,35H0V0C23.6,0,18.2,35,30,35z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="product-info tabbable">
    <div class="row">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">
                    <div class="tabbed">
                        <div class="left">
                                    <div class="tabText"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="middle">
                        <div class="tabText">Details</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="right">
                           <div class="tabText"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">
                    <div class="tabbed">
                     <div class="left">
                        <div class="tabText"></div>
                     </div>
                        <div class="middle"><div class="tabText">Other important specification</div></div>
                        <div class="right">
                           <div class="tabText"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="tab-content">
            lorem ipsum
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! this is definitely something to chew on, I didn't know how to implement it but I was thinking that there should be 2 (sides + middle) or 3 classes (right+middle+left) inside the svg... sorry that I didn't wrote out from start the svg code unescaped and that I'm after a pure html+svg+css solution, so preferably no javascript adjustments.

Comment: sure, I understand - it seemed frustrating to me not to be able to do this in a simpler way! Are you open to splitting the SVG into 3 parts, and adding those to the CSS classes as bgs? That might solve the issue, as you can adjust the middle div's width - just a guess though.

Comment: I updated with the CSS only example - still feels a bit hacky, but this may be as good as you can do without Javascript - I don't think you can morph the middle of the SVG without JS unless you use 3 separate images in the classes.

Comment: my latest example is not perfect - just a first stab at a pure CSS approach! The elements don't line up perfectly, which bothers me - I hadn't seen your additional edits above, I'll take a look at those links. I'm the developer of https://kwippe.com, so SVG is something I'm really interested in :)

Comment: By the way I used this base64 encoder - https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/ - and the 3 SVG files with each tab element aligned to 0,0 are here https://github.com/mspanish/playground

Comment: this is much better, but basically this puts me back from where I tried to escape from: messing with 3 html elements instead of one, a thing that can cause frustrations when it should behave the same way on all the modern browsers (IE11) included. Added an svg of how I imagine one kind of solution, but ultimatley if that or something to the same effect can not be achieved this would be accepted.

Comment: is this just an exercise for you, or are you really needing to use this graphic in this way? Seems like a lot of trouble for a tab that you can code in another way! But as for the SVG exercise, it's interesting and I hope you get some more people reply as I'd like to see alternate ways of doing it. As far as I know, you cannot alter SVG properties if the SVG is used as a BG image, but maybe somebody else knows something I don't.

Comment: more of an exercise but of course because I think something useful could come out of it :), thanks for your efforts, me too waiting for others to catch up on this thread.